# Spectral analysis of periodic table of elements in time domain

Tags: computational-chemistry, spectroscopy

I'm trying to get the spectral analysis data of the periodic table of elements in the **time domain format** or find a site that has the data in the **time domain format**.  All the sites
I know have the data in the frequency domain which is great but **I need to do my own fft analysis starting from the time domain because the frequency domain does not include the phase angle data, which I also need to use for my calculations/animations**.

Does anyone know where I can get this data or can someone send me the spectral analysis data for sodium and potassium in the time domain?

Thanks

Comment: What do you need the time domain for? Depending on what you need them for, you could just take the frequency domain data and do an inverse fourier transform.

Comment: @Dan That won't work since the phase angle information is not included when you use the frequency domain, that is the reason I need to start from the time domain

Comment: What do you need this for? Why do you need the phase angle?

Comment: @Dan sorry if the question wasn't clear but I need to run my own fft analysis starting from the time domain not the frequency domain because I also need the phase angle data to use in my calculations/animations. I'll update the question. If this is the wrong forum to ask this question can someone tell me the correct one.

Comment: The question was clear on that point. What I want to know is why you need to run your own FFT analysis and what you need that phase angle data for.

Comment: Also, what frequency range do you want the data in? If it's IR or higher, said tables probably don't exist. It's hard to get phase information at those frequencies, and the measurements are made directly in the frequency domain.

Comment: Its unclear what you want. Is it the lifetime of excited states of atoms, or IR spectra as a function of time as a species reacts or what? Absorption or emission spectra can only very rarely be used to get time information as the line shapes are distorted by process such as Doppler and collisional broadening and inverting is then pointless.